# How to access an IIS Express site on Windows 11 from a remote computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, iis-express

How to access an IIS Express site on **Windows 11** from a remote computer?

I'm able to make it works on **Windows 10** (via Parallel Desktop 15 on my MacBook Pro intel chip with MacOS Monterey) by following this article [Accessing an IIS Express site from a remote computer](https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer/).

But it doesn't work when I did the same thing on **Windows 11** (via Parallel Desktop 18 on my company MacBook Pro M1 chip with MacOS Monterey). So I guess Windows 11 causes the issue.

FYI, following are the steps I used to make it works on Windows 10:

1. Bind the app to your public IP Address.

- Open Command Prompt in Windows with Admin right. -> Type `ipconfig`. -> Noted the value of IPv4 Address. Assuming its IPv4 Address is `xx.xxx.xx.5`.
- Open the `/{project folder}/.vs/config/applicationhost.config`. -> At line `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:41036:localhost" />`, add another line `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:41036:xx.xxx.xx.5" />`.

2. Allow incoming connections.
   Run the following cmds:

```bash
netsh http add urlacl url=http://xx.xxx.xx.5:41036/ user=everyone
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=41036 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

Now I can access the site in MacOS using `http://xx.xxx.xx.5:41036/weatherforecast`.

Comment: iis express isn't really designed for that - can't you just install iis proper?

Comment: @DanielA.White What is IIS Proper?

Comment: The real iis that comes with windows

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Conveyor it's a free(mium) extension for Visual Studio, you can get it from the extensions menu.

It allows access from devices on your LAN or over the internet through tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [IIS Express Proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iisexpress-proxy) as a bit of a hack to access services hosted on IIS Express from VMs before (in Xamarin app development specifically). However, as has been pointed out in the comments, your best option may just be use to use IIS proper.

Comment: @ madmonk46 what is IIS Proper? I tried the IIS Express Proxy and it works on Windows 10 but doesn't work on Windows 11.

Comment: @TuanvanDuong IIS Express is designed for local testing only, so it's not configured to allow connections from external machines. That proxy software gets around that problem. The "full" version of IIS can be installed in the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" settings window. Then you can install your app as you normally would on Windows Server through IIS Manager. Regarding the Windows 11 specific issue you're having, I'm unsure whether it'll help or not but it's probably worth doing anyway to make your life easier in the long run.